# replace NA values with sequence

Tags: r

I am trying to fill in some NA values of a string but count the NA values that are being filled.

For example I have the following string:

```
string = c("A", "B", "C", NA, NA, "D", "E", NA, "F", "G", NA, NA)
```

Expected output:

```
"A", "B", "C", "NA_VALUE_1", "NA_VALUE_2", "D", "E", "NA_VALUE_3", "F", "G", "NA_VALUE_4", "NA_VALUE_5"
```

So, I want to paste the sequence `paste("NA_VALUE_", valueHere)` where `valueHere` increases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n_na = sum(is.na(string))
string[is.na(string)] <- paste0("NA_VALUE_", seq_len(n_na))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```r
ifelse(a <- is.na(string), paste0("NA_VALUE_", cumsum(a)), string)

# [1] "A"          "B"          "C"          "NA_VALUE_1" "NA_VALUE_2" "D"          "E"         
# [8] "NA_VALUE_3" "F"          "G"          "NA_VALUE_4" "NA_VALUE_5"
```

Because `is.na(string)` need to be used twice in this method, I store it as a new object `a` in the first part of `ifelse()` so that I can pass it into `cumsum()` afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::iwalk`:

```r
library(purrr)

iwalk(which(is.na(string)), ~ {string[.x] <<- paste0("NA_Value_", .y)})
string

#>  [1] "A"          "B"          "C"          "NA_Value_1" "NA_Value_2"
#>  [6] "D"          "E"          "NA_Value_3" "F"          "G"         
#> [11] "NA_Value_4" "NA_Value_5"
```